# How to execute .rb with arguments via Jruby from java

Tags: java, runtime, arguments, jruby

I have parse_files.rb ruby file which contains code for parsing different files
I use it from console like this

```
 ruby parse_file.rb -x -l -a path/to/source/files/*filepattern
```

I want to do the same but from java code via jruby.
The question is :how to invoke script execution of this file with  "-x -l -a path/to/source/files/*filepattern" arguments via Ruby runtime? 
is it possible to do with evalScriptlet(String str) or something else?